# How to make sure that points drawn on JFrame at random location does not overlap already drawn shapes?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating 100 particles at random location all over my JPanel using random function to calculate x and y. But I have two rectangles also drawn on the panel and I do not want my points to overlap on that area.

Is there any way, by which I can create the particles all over the JPanel except those areas covered by rectangle?

```
            int x,y=0;
            super.paintComponent(g);

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                x=randomInteger(11,670); // bounds of x between which the particles should be generated (reduced by 1 each)
                y=randomInteger(11,440);   // bounds of y between which the particles should be generated (reduced by 1 each)
                int radius = 4;
                g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);
            }

            x=randomInteger(11,670); 
            y=randomInteger(11,440);

            drawRobot(g,x,y,50);
            createObstacles(g,150,225,100,40);
            createObstacles(g,500,300,40,100);

            int xpoints[] = {50, 40, 60, 120};
            int ypoints[] = {50, 75, 100, 130};
            int npoints = 4;
            createPolygonObstacle(g,xpoints,ypoints,npoints);          

        }

        private void createPolygonObstacle(Graphics g, int xpoints[], int ypoints[], int npoints)
        {
             g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
        }

        private void createObstacles(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

        private void drawRobot(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);           
        }

        private static int randomInteger(int min, int max)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            return randomNum;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `Shape` API...

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (x, y, width, height);
```

Then you could use it's `contains` method to determine if it contains a given point...

```
if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
    // You bad little particle...
}
```

You should also know that the `Graphics2D` can also draw and paint `Shape`, so you could also do...

```
((Graphics2D)g).fill(rect);
```

Which should make your life some what easier.  As of Java 1.4 (I think), the paint engine is guaranteed to use `Graphics2D`, so your `paintComponent` method will always receive an instance of a `Graphics2D` object.

Take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: @user3097157 Hope it all helps

Comment: Actually, I got what you meant here, but there is an issue i m facing now. I am calling this all in a constructor of a different class. If I use Rectangle of Shape API. How will I add it to my panel? Any idea?

Comment: I would imagine you could create some kind of model, which describes the state of the world.  You would then update the model accordingly and then paint it

Comment: Hmm, I am sorry not able to get you.

Comment: Create another class, which models the virtual state of your world.  Maintains information about where paricales are, where objects are.  You could use `Point` and `Rectangle` to do this, but that's up to you.  You would create this model in the constructor and then pass it to whatever is rendering/updating the state of the world.  The panel would use the model to determine what to paint and the updater would determine what needs to be updated (or instructs the model that it should update)

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random();
public void generateParticle(){
    int x = r.nextInt();
    int y = r.nextInt();
    if(x > LeftEdgeOfRectangle || x < RightEdgeOfRectangle){
         generateParticle();
         return();
    }
    if(y > TopEdgeOfRectangle || y < BottomEdgeOfRectangle){
         generateParticle();
         return();
    }
    [drawParticleHere]
}
```